# Linear Algebra: Solving for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $k$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm really struggling to grasp this one:

> Find conditions on $k$ that will make the following system of equations
> have a unique solution. To enter your answer, first select whether $k$
> should be equal or not equal to specific values, then enter a value or
> a list of values separated by commas.
>
> Then give a formula in terms of $k$ for the solution to the system, when
> it exists. Be sure to include parentheses where necessary, e.g. to
> distinguish 1/(2k) from 1/2k.
>
> $\begin{cases}3kx+12y = 3 \\ 8x+2ky = 5\end{cases}$

I know how to *find* $k$, but I'm not so sure on how to find $x$ and $y$ (in terms of $k$).
Can someone explain, in detail on how to do this? Please and thank you.

Comment: Use substitution method.

Comment: Think of $k$ as though it were a constant.  Then solve for $x$ and $y$ just like you would if $3k$ and $2k$ were any other integers.  (For example: top equation gives us $y =\frac {3-3kx}{12}$ and plugging that into the bottom we get $8x + 2k(\frac {3-3kx}{12} = 5$ and solve for $x$ etc.... or we could multiply the top by $k$ and the bottom by $6$ and subtract.....

Comment: Just do it.

We solve $2x + 3y = 4$ and $5x + 6y = 7$ by doing:

$2x + 3y =4\implies$  
$3y = 4-2x\implies$   
$y=\frac {4-2x}3\implies$   
$5x + 6(\frac {4-2x}3)=7\implies$   
$5x +8 -4x = 7\implies$   
$x=-1\implies$   
$y = \frac {4-2\cdot (-1)}3=2$

So just do that... but use $3k$ instead of $2$ and $12$ instead of $3$ and $3$ instead of $4$ and $8$ instead of $5$ and $2k$ instead of $6$ and $5$ instead of $7$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've found that k absolute value mustn't be equal to 4.
Now, your only parameter is k & x & y are unknown & we have AX = b. You simply need to calculate inverse of A & multiply it from the left side to the b. I can show you the answer by MATLAB programming.

A = [3*k, 12;8,2*k]
X = [x;y]
b = [3;5]

A inverse = [ k/(3*(k^2 - 16)),  -2/(k^2 - 16); -4/(3*(k^2 - 16)), k/(2*(k^2 - 16))]

Answer:
x = k/(k^2 - 16) - 10/(k^2 - 16) &
y = (5*k)/(2*(k^2 - 16)) - 4/(k^2 - 16)

If there's anymore question, please ask in the comments.